# Searching for words that are composed entirely from a list of root words

Tags: python, nltk

I'm new to coding in general and thought now would be a good time to teach myself some Python.

What I'm currently trying to achieve is to determine a list of words that are entirely made up from a variable set of root words, syllables, prefixes and suffixes that I will choose.

This is where I'm up to so far;

```
from nltk.corpus import words as english

vocab = set(w.lower() for w in english.words())

syllables = ('in', 'con', 'sis', 'tent', 'tant', 'si', 'ate', 'der', 'ing', 'a', 'c', 't')

syl_set=set(syllables)

for word in vocab:

    if all(x in syl_set for x in set(word)):

        print (word)
```

With the help of the NLTK install with the Words corpus downloaded, I'm able to search through a list of English words and output a list of the words that are composed of individual letters in my syllables list (shown above) e.g cat, tact.

However this does not output words that are composed of the strings that are longer than one letter e.g consistent, considerate.

Could someone please explain why these multi-letter strings aren't being used to find the words that they could spell out?
Also any advice on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: What word would have every one of those syllables in there

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not looking for a word with all of these syllables, just a list of words that can be made entirely from the syllables in the list. e.g consistent, considerate, considering, inconsistent etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason is that you are just looking for single characters. Have a look at this part: `for x in set(word)`. This one iterates through all *letters* in the set of all characters contained in `word`.

Have a look at the result from

```py
[x for x in set(word)]
```

to see what I mean.

Solving this could be tricky. Splitting a word into syllables is harder than splitting it into characters.

Comment: Hi Lydia, yes I see what you mean. Thanks for your response.